# Battery charge limiter on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, battery, charging

I have been searching the internet for quite a while to find an app, which will limit the battery charge on my laptop, but all of them are limited to notifications when the battery reaches a certain percentage, but what I want is something Asus is doing, which is capping the battery on, say, 80% and preventing it from charging further even if it is plugged in. I am currently using a Xiaomi laptop with windows 10 installed and I wonder if there is a way to do something like this on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all Notebooks (in fact only a minority) have the necessary hardware to switch charging on and off via i driver (i.e. via software). In the majority of computers the process of charging is controlled by a dedicated controller that will report the charging state but not allow it to be influenced by software.

Most likely your Xiaomi lacks this feature, so the charge limiting applications just can't do it.

Comment: Probably, yes. But maybe there is a way, I should ask on Xiaomi forums as well I guess. Although I know that rooted android phones can do that. But I understand that phones are a different story

Comment: This is wishful thinking. The chances are so small that your laptop has this, because if it had it, the software necessary would be preinstalled on your laptop.

Comment: Not even all phones have this ability - I own a cheap Chinadroid, that definitly doesn't